# I want to do a Caesar cipher code app for android

Tags: java, android

For normal text after i inserted it in edit_text : Why can't i get the text coded when i enter capital X Y Z , i get these [ \ ] symbols and normally i should get A B C , for non capital letters seems to work when i press x y z i get a b c ... and also when i press space i get this # symbol...

and for decoding ..the reverse process : when i press a b c i get these
 symbols ^ _ ` normmaly i should get x y z and for capital letters A B C i get these > ? @  normally i should get capital X Y Z... but when i press space here seems to work and doesn't display #

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    TextView myText, myText2;
    Button myCodeButton, myDecodeButton, deleteButton;
    public static EditText enteredEditText;
    public String getText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // text for showing coded and decoded words
        myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        myText2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        //edittext
        enteredEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        //buttons
        myCodeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        myDecodeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        deleteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);


        Code_My_TextButton();  
        Decode_my_textButton();

        // this is just for clearing edit_texts and text_views
        deleteClick();
    }


// i entered a text and this method should code the text and display it
    public void Code_My_TextButton()
    {
        myCodeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Caesar_cipher_coding_method();
                myText2.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

    private void Caesar_cipher_coding_method() {
        int shift = 3; // the shift is for A is going to be A + 3 letters
       // and would be D , for B will be E , for C will be F and so on..
        Editable msg = enteredEditText.getText();
        String s = "";
        int len = msg.length();
        for (int x = 0; x < len; x++) {
            char c = (char) (msg.charAt(x) + shift);
            if (c > 'z')
                s += (char) (msg.charAt(x) - (26 - shift));
            else
                s += (char) (msg.charAt(x) + shift);


        }
        myText.setText(s);
    }


    public void Decode_my_textButton()
    {
        myDecodeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Reverse_Caesar_cipher_coding_method();

            }
        });
    }
// here is the reverse process ...i enter the coded word and should show me 
//the normal word
    private void Reverse_Caesar_cipher_coding_method() {
        int shift = -3;
        Editable msg = enteredEditText.getText();
        String s = "";
        int len = msg.length();
        for (int x = 0; x < len; x++) {
            char c = (char) (msg.charAt(x) + shift);
            if (c > 'z')
                s += (char) (msg.charAt(x) - (26 - shift));
            else
                s += (char) (msg.charAt(x) + shift);


        }
        myText2.setText(s);
        myText.setText("");
    }

    // this is just for clearing edit_texts and text_views
    public void deleteClick()
    {
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
           //clearing text
                enteredEditText.setText("");
                myText.setText("");
                myText2.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: A simpler de/coding method would be the ASCII `xor 1` method. You xor each ASCII with 1 for both coding and decoding. Very easy.

Answer (score 1):

During the encryption, there is another condition.
For example:

```
//in the Caesar cipher
for (int x = 0; x < len; x++) {
    char c = (char) (msg.charAt(x) + shift);
    if (c > 'z' || ( c > 'Z' && c < 'd')) { // if the shifted went past z or Z:
        c-=26;
    }
    s+=c;
}

//in the reverse
for (int x = 0; x < len; x++) {
    char c = (char) (msg.charAt(x) + shift);
    if (c < 'A' || (c < 'a' && c > 'W'))
        c += 26;
    s += c;
}
myText2.setText(s);
myText.setText("");
```

Comment: let me see il try now

Comment: seems to work but what about that space thing...when i press space shows # for coding word

Comment: any ideea about space ?

Comment: in the coding if i press space shows # and in the decoding when i press space shows 7 the number...how can you fix that?